# Call child method from parent class - React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

How do I call a child method from parent class ? or to put it simply how to assign a ref to ReactElement?

I've seen examples where ref is assigned to HTMLDivElement or HTMLInputElement, but not a ReactElement.

```
class Example extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  ...
  childRef = React.createRef<React.ReactElement>();
  ...
  next = () => {
    this.childRef.someFunction();
  }

  render() {
    <Child ref={this.childRef}/>
  }
}
```

The above code gives me two errors:

```
Generic type 'ReactElement<P>' requires 1 type argument(s).
Property 'someFunction' does not exist on type 'RefObject<any>'.
```

Comment: Try this: `childRef = React.createRef<React.ReactElement<YourChildComponent>>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is `React.createRef<React.ReactElement>()`. You need to change `ReactElement` to the type that you want, in this case `Child`.

One more issue in `this.childRef.someFunction();`. It's missing `.current`. then it'll be `this.childRef.current.someFunction();`.

Here's a full example:

[Or try live demo on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/mzwmnp7qyp?autoresize=1&hidenavigation=1)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface ChildState {
  lastCalled?: Date
}

class Child extends React.Component<{}, ChildState> {
  state: ChildState = {};

  render() {
    if (!this.state.lastCalled) {
      return "Not called yet";
    }

    return `Last called at ${this.state.lastCalled.toLocaleTimeString()}`;
  }

  someFunction = () => {
    this.setState({
      lastCalled: new Date()
    });
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  childRef = React.createRef<Child>();

  next = () => {
    if (!this.childRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    this.childRef.current.someFunction();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Child ref={this.childRef} />
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.next}>
            Next Call
          </button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

#### Update -- 16 May 2019:

When I opened the CodeSandBox sample above and updated to latest dependencies, it didn't seem to like:

```
childRef = React.createRef<Child>();
```

It throws an error on the close bracket `)`.

To make it work, I changed it to:

```
childRef:React.RefObject<Child> = React.createRef();
```

[image: Edit gallant-ganguly-0puxy]

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: I tried this approach but I get someFunction() is undefined. Yet, it still works except for the error message

Comment: Try the exact CodeSandBox version I posted in the update please, and then compare it to your code.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `React.createRef()`, the resulting object looks like `{current : null}`.  React then assigns whatever the actual reference is to `refObject.current`.

So, in your example, you need `this.childRef.current.someFunction()`.

You may also have to do some TypeScript declarations to let it know the object stored inside the ref has that function available.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the .current

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass in a function to assign the reference variable.

```
private childRef: any;
private assignRef = (ref) => this.childRef = ref;

next = () => {
    this.childRef.someFunction();
}

render() {
    <Child ref={this.assignRef}/>
}
```